# jQuery - Click Event is not Working as a Blur Event fires And Changes Dom Heights

Tags: jquery

Please take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fyc5d/

Click a gray box, and you'll see the textarea box open. Now click another. Click going up and then click going down the boxes.

You'll notice it works fine going up from the last gray box to the top gray box. but it break when going top/down. It appears  this is occurring because when because the elements are bluring first, which is changing their dimensions.

Specific use case to reproduce:

- Click Box 1
- Notice the textarea shows
- Click Box 2
- Notice box 1 was hidden which is good. But box 2 did not open, which was the expected behavior.

Ideas, thoughts? Any elegant way to solve for this without a bunch of timeouts? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fyc5d/3/). If you have trouble understanding it, please ask.

Comment: Your solution simply drops handling blur event as a whole. As a consequence, textareas don't hide on losing focus. That's a major issue (for me who am looking for a coexistence of blur and click).